# Cycles Hates My Materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, texture-baking

So I have this lovely shield I put together as a first time project in Eevee.

[image: Eevee Shield]

It looks great, I'm excited, but I need to bake it apparently so I can have all those lovely colors on the FBX file or something like it, supposedly. So I do as I'm told and switch over to Cycles to bake it and...

[image: Cycles Shield]

Nope. It's decided only the bottom most material gets to exist, and color ramps are just nonexistent. What gives? I've been at this for hours and I'm at a loss!

[image]

Comment: The shader to RGB node does not work with cycles.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Apart from the _Shader to RGB_ node not working in _Cycles_, it looks like you have created a black outline object using _Backface Culling_ to be only visible around the shield. Backface culling also does not work in _Cycles_ like in _Eevee_, you have to create it manually in the shader. And for the _Color Ramp_ disappearing, read this: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)